# Why the shorter the memory latency, the smaller the cache block

Tags: caching, memory

I have a book statement:

> The shorter the memory latency, the smaller the cache block.

I don't understand it. In my current understanding the memory latency is the time required for a data movement. So it seems like a smaller cache block means less amount to be sent, so it's quicker?

The answer gives: *A lower miss penalty can enable smaller blocks, since you don't have that much latency to amortize*. Which is currently useless statement for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a simple consequence of the limited speed of light. Signals need time to travel. For a copper wire it is ca. 20cm/ns. If you have a memory chips 10cm away from your CPU you can send a signal with ACK with a rate of 1 GHz (0,5 ns to send the data from CPU to memory and 0,5 ns from memory to CPU for the ACK).

If you put the memory modules nearer to the CPU lets say only 5 cm you can reduce the cache by some margin because you are already two times faster and the benefit of the cache will be less.

Comment: take your 10k sir.